# Infinite Scroll RecycleView with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

Okay guy, first of all I have read this [blog](https://hackernoon.com/naive-infinite-scroll-in-reactive-programming-using-rxjs-observables-4a605d3146e8) post about (Naive Infinite scroll in Reactive Programming using RxJS Observables) and want to try it with RecycleView on Android.

Here is result and my code...

**RESULT**

[image]

**ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String[] NAME = {"JONG", "MARCH", "BANK", "TAR", "VIJAYA", "JAMES", "OAT", "POOH", "BOW", "NAN"};

    private int currentPage = 1;
    private RecyclerView rcvInfinite;
    private MainAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<MainListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean isFetchingApi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rcvInfinite = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcvInfinite);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("PAGE", currentPage);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("LISTITEM", listItems);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("PAGE", currentPage);
            listItems = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("LISTITEM");
        }

        if (listItems == null || listItems.isEmpty()) {
            listItems = getListItem(currentPage);
            ++currentPage;
        }

        adapter = new MainAdapter(this, listItems);
        rcvInfinite.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rcvInfinite.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        rcvInfinite.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        rcvInfinite.setAdapter(adapter);

        ScrollDownPercentageObservable scrollDownPercentageObservable =
                new ScrollDownPercentageObservable(rcvInfinite, 70);

        Observable.create(scrollDownPercentageObservable)
                .filter(scroll70f -> {
                    if (scroll70f && !isFetchingApi) {
                        isFetchingApi = true;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .concatMap(scroll70f -> fetchRemoteData())
                .delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((next) -> {
                    ++currentPage;
                    listItems.addAll(next);
                    adapter.setItems(listItems);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    isFetchingApi = false;
                }, (error) -> {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }, () -> {
                });
    }

    private Observable<ArrayList<MainListItem>> fetchRemoteData() {
        return Observable.create(e -> {
            // mock data
            ArrayList<MainListItem> listItems1 = getListItem(currentPage);

            // emit
            e.onNext(listItems1);
            e.onComplete();
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    private ArrayList<MainListItem> getListItem(int page) {
        ArrayList<MainListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        int lastIndex = page * 10;
        int firstIndex = lastIndex - (10 - 1);
        for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
            listItems.add(new MainListItem(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%03d", i), NAME[i % 10]));
        }
        return listItems;
    }

    private class ScrollDownPercentageObservable implements ObservableOnSubscribe<Boolean> {

        private final RecyclerView mRecycleView;
        private final int mPercentage;
        private ObservableEmitter<Boolean> emitter;

        public ScrollDownPercentageObservable(RecyclerView recycleView, int percentage) {
            mRecycleView = recycleView;
            mPercentage = percentage;
            mRecycleView.addOnScrollListener(onScroll);
        }

        private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScroll = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView rcv, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(rcv, dx, dy);
                if (emitter != null) {
                    if (dy > 0) {
                        // Scrolling up
                        Log.v("SCROLL", "SCROLL UP");
                        LinearLayoutManager lm = (LinearLayoutManager) rcv.getLayoutManager();
                        int pos = lm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                        int itemCount = rcv.getAdapter().getItemCount();
                        int itemViewedPercentage = (int) ((pos / (float) itemCount) * 100);
                        emitter.onNext(itemViewedPercentage >= mPercentage);
                    } else {
                        // Scrolling down
                        Log.v("SCROLL", "SCROLL DOWN");
                        emitter.onNext(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Boolean> e) throws Exception {
            emitter = e;
        }
    }
}
```

It working as show in result, but I want to know, **Is there any RxJava way to achieve the same result without using following flag ?**

> boolean isFetchingApi;

**Why I use it ?**

It's because when `onScrolled` meet the condition (scroll to 70% of items), observable will emit item very fast. Result in api (mock data) was requested too many time for each page. In conclusion this flag use for stop receiving stream of result from `onScrolled`.

Any idea or else, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, But maybe you could do something with flowable and request as many items as you want?